# shell script: run a block of code in the background without defining a new function?

Tags: shell, background

Is there a way to 'inline' a block of code the run in the background without defining the block as a function? I was thinking something like:

```
( do something; a bit more; finally this ) &
( more things; etc ...; ) &
wait
proceed ...
```

I suppose it's only one line extra define a single-use function and then immediately use it but I was curious and didn't find anything searching.

Comment: What failed with what you have there?

Comment: If you thought posted pseudo-code, you actually got the syntax exactly right. `(cmd; cmd; cmd) &` followed by `wait` if you want to wait for the background processes to finish is spot on.

Comment: Yes, I thought posted pseudo code. I thought I tried it out properly and got a fail but I must have done something stupid in my test. :) thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
{
    echo "sleeping for 5 seconds"
    sleep 5
    echo "woke up"
} &
echo "waiting"
wait
echo "proceed"
```

#### Output

```
$ ./bgblock
waiting
sleeping for 5 seconds
woke up
proceed
```

Comment: Can someone clarify in a way that is easy to remember what the functional difference is between `{ cmd; cmd; } &` and `( cmd; cmd; ) &`?

Comment: I tried to write `{ cmd || cmd2 } &` and vim told me my bash syntax wasn't right. So I went with parens instead. So there definitely is a difference here.

Comment: Yes `{...}` does NOT create a sub-shell whereas `(...)` does.  The reason for your error is that you tried to background something that didn’t create a sub-shell

Comment: Thanks @SiegeX for the explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

I could do it with something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
{
    echo "sleeping for 5 seconds"
    sleep 5
    echo "woke up"
} 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 1):

well that is not (completely) true what SiegeX replied to Steven Lou
the reason why syntax
    { cmd || cmd2 } &
did not work is because it should be as such:
    { cmd || cmd2 ;} &

Comment: Indeed, '{ true || true; } &` works. This would have been better as a reply in the original thread, but since you can't reply to it yet, here's an upvote.